tmutil delete returns error 22 while deleting backups in external drive to free up space
$tmutil listbackups
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2023-12-26-145443.backup/2023-12-26-145443.backup
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2024-01-04-172522.backup/2024-01-04-172522.backup
.
.
.
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2024-04-15-161738.backup/2024-04-15-161738.backup
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2024-04-15-173852.backup/2024-04-15-173852.backup

Those were my backups in APFS-formatted external drive (those timepoints show up when I attach the external drive and enter Time Machine), but I am getting errors when using tmutil delete to remove any backup points e.g. 2023-12-26-145443.backup. The goal is to free up space in the external drive.
$ sudo tmutil delete /Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2023-12-26-145443.backup/2023-12-26-145443.backup
Specify either a path or a mountpoint and timestamp
Usage: tmutil delete [-d backup_mount_point -t timestamp] [-p path]
$ sudo tmutil delete -p /Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2023-12-26-145443.backup/2023-12-26-145443.backup
Password:
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2023-12-26-145443.backup/2023-12-26-145443.backup: Invalid deletion target (error 22)
Total deleted: Zero KB

The -p flag is not working. Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Why do you need to manually delete from the TM drive vs allowing TM to thin the backups?

@MarcWilson, ideally I should have specified the quota size for the Time Machine to 500 GB when creating the APFS volume. Wishing to utilize half of the 1TB external drive for other purposes and not more than half for TM backups. Now cannot do that without removing all the old backups, right?

@LincD., thanks it takes me to the right direction I believe but not fully, e.g. sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/.timemachine -t 2024-04-15-010955 returns error -
(null): Undefined error: 0 (error 0)`.

Oops, this should be easy but the help section for tmutil isn't very user friendly.
Confusion arises because of the following - Backups are listed as in internal volume but they are not!
$ tmutil listbackups
.
.
.
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2024-04-15-010955.backup/2024-04-15-010955.backup
.
.
.
/Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/2024-04-15-181828.backup/2024-04-15-181828.backup

So this fails:
sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/.timemachine -t 2024-04-15-010955
(null): Undefined error: 0 (error 0)

However, thanks to Linc D., whose suggestion led me to the right direction:
$ sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/TimeMachineSDEP -t 2024-04-15-010955
Password:
1 backups deleted

So, the TimeMachineSDEP is the external drive (more correctly, the APFS volume) mounted at /Volumes/ and 2024-04-15-010955 is one backup at particular a date and time. /Volumes/.timemachine/96F5062D-1718-4C7F-A137-D0C6EC70AF68/ is a temporary directory in the Mac where the backups are mounted.
